# Why do inline awaits, apparently, run synchronously but awaits on Deferreds run in parallel?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

In the following `telemeter` function, I measure elapsed time for two blocks of code. The first declares `Deferred`s which are later `await`ed. The second `await`s each `Deferred` inline.

Since `await` claims to *"Awaits for completion of this value without blocking a thread"*[1](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html), I would expect them both to run concurrently, yet this only seems the case with the first block.

Does this have to do with [lazily started asyncs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#lazily-started-async)? Why the difference in behavior?
Thanks

```
private suspend fun telemeter() {
    coroutineScope {
        val t0 = measureTimeMillis {
            val d0 = async { delay1s() }
            val d1 = async { delay1s() }
            d0.await()
            d1.await()
        }
        println("DEFERREDS: ${t0}s")
        val t1 = measureTimeMillis {
            async { delay1s() }.await()
            async { delay1s() }.await()
        }
        println("INLINE   : ${t1}s")
    }
}

private suspend fun delay1s() = delay(1000)
```

Output:

```
DEFERREDS: 1003s
INLINE   : 2003s
```

Comment: It does not block the thread, but it suspends the currznt coroutine. It means that your coroutine won't try to launch the second async block before await resume the coroutine. A coroutine is sequential. The thread, as it is not blocked, can be used concurrently by another coroutine.

Comment: @amanin, that seems to explain the behavior of the "inline" async-await calls, but then why are the awaited declared `Deferred`s, apparently, run in parallel? Thanks

Comment: In your `INLINE` example, you don't start the second `async` after the first `await` returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In example 1, you create two asynchronous tasks.  They immediately start running.  Then you wait on the result of each of them (remember they both already started).  So that wait is in parallel, because both are running and will finish approximately the same time..

In example 2, you create 1 asynchronous task, and wait for it to finish.  Then you create another and wait for it to finish.  So they run consecutively.

If you had gone

```
    val t1 = measureTimeMillis {
        val d1 = async { delay1s() }
        async { delay1s() }.await()
        d1.await()
    }
```

those also would have occurred in parallel, because d1 was started as soon as the async call was made, so it will be done by the time the first await finishes.

If you had gone:

```
    val t1 = measureTimeMillis {
        async { delay1s() }.await()
        val d1 = async { delay1s() }
        d1.await()
    }
```

then you would have created and waited for the first async, then created and waited for the second, so they would run consecutively.